# Excel Userform listbox header assistance

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am currently building an excel userform where I can search the results from the worksheet I have tagged in and i can then select the data to be editted across the columns. This is the first time I have worked with userforms so this is fairly new to me.

I have figured out the functionality aspect of the listbox but am struggling on the display of it. The worksheet has 13 columns which I need to show but the current code only me some and the alignment and headers are not able to be shown. I have tried to add it but it would not come out the way I hoped. Would anyone have any corrections or tips for what I can do to make the headers (they are in B2 to N2) to be shown constantly and have the data that gets shown as I search to be displayed within the columns?

Here is the VBA code.

```vb
Private Sub listbox_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim matchFound As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If listbox.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        For i = 3 To lastRow
            If listbox.List(listbox.ListIndex) = ws.Cells(i, 2) & vbTab & ws.Cells(i, 3) & vbTab & ws.Cells(i, 10) Then
                matchFound = True
                column1.Text = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                column2.Text = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
                column3.Text = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                column4.Text = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
                column5.Text = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
                column6.Text = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
                column7.Text = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
                column8.Text = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
                column9.Text = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value
                column10.Text = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value
                column11.Text = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value
                column12.Text = ws.Cells(i, 13).Value
                column13.Text = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
                
                ' Store the row number in the worksheet to be used when edit button is clicked
                selectedRow = i
                
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    If Not matchFound Then
        For Each ctl In Frame2.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                ctl.Value = ""
            End If
        Next ctl
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried the following

1. Set the Columnheads to be true and the columncount to 13.
2. Add the column head and column count in the VBA code
3. Referenced this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdscD-1TDq0) to see, i couldn't find the activate in the VBA editor.

What I was hoping from it would be the headers that are in B2 to N2 to be shown permanently and cannot be clicked. As I have a statement where if something is clicked it should pull the data into another frame.

Comment: Not many people here will spend time to watch a video to figure out what you're trying to do - it's better to explain directly in the post.